# Why are my inbound Twilio sms messages stuck in the "queued" state?

Tags: sms, twilio

Most of the messages that I send from my phone to Twilio are sitting out there "queued". That's odd because the documentation makes it sound like that status doesn't even apply to incoming messages "The API request to send an message was successful and the message is queued to be sent out" at least that's how I read it. I wouldn't care that they are queued as they are readable and a I can process them, but I cannot delete them in that status. Twilio throws an error.
So how can I get their status going OR how can I delete them in a queued state? Bonus question, is there a big red button on the website that just flushes everything out? I'm using the Rest API fwiw.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently an issue on the part of Twilio. You can see the status here.

http://status.twilio.com/

Comment: Very good. Thanks for the link. I came across a different status page but not that one. Good to know about!